# Is there a way to make elements overlap in LazyRow/ LazyColumn

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have images that i would want to overlap a little from the side by the next image in the LazyRow. I tried settings the Modifiers offset with a negative value but it only cut the images, rather than overlaping them.

```
LazyRow(  modifier = Modifier
                .align(CenterStart), verticalAlignment = CenterVertically
        ) {
            items(pictures.take(6)){
                    AsyncImage(modifier = Modifier
                        .size(32.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape).offset((-10).dp, 0.dp),
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                            .data(it)
                            .crossfade(true)
                            .build(),
                        placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_person),
                        contentDescription =null,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop )
            }
}
```

Comment: `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-32).dp)` add a negativevalue for spacing of items

Comment: you can do it with custom layout and placing items with horizontal percentage